# find $\angle{DAC}$

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle{ABC}$, given $\angle{A}=80^\circ$, $\angle{B}=\angle{C}=50^\circ$, D is a point in $\triangle{ABC}$, which $\angle{DBC}=20^\circ,\angle{DCB}=40^\circ$. Then how to find find $\angle{DAC}$?

thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this isn't the same kind of problem as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63819/determine-angle-x-using-only-elementary-geometry/63833#63833

Comment: (didn't do a careful check, but...) possible duplicate of [Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the geometric method but could not succeed. However the trigonometric route yields the result.
Here it is:
Extend $CD$ to meet $AB$ at $G$. Angle $B$ is $50$. Angle $BCD$ is $40$. So $CG$ is perpendicular to $AB$.
Let $AH$ be the right bisector of angle $A$ resting on $BC$ at $H$. Let the required angle $DAC$ be $k$ degrees.
$$
GD = AG\tan(80-k) = BG\tan(30),
$$
$$
\tan(80-k) = \frac{GD}{AG} = {BG\tan(30)}{AG}.
$$
$$
BG = BC\cos(50)
$$
$$
BC = 2BH = 2AB\cos(50).
$$
So, 
$$
BG = 2AB\cos(50) \cos(50)
$$
$$
AG = AC \cos(80) = AB \cos(80)
$$
So, 
$$
\tan(80-k) = \frac{BG\tan(30)}{AG} = \frac{2\cos )(50) \cos (50) \tan (30)}{\cos(80)}
$$
$$
80-k = \arctan\left(\frac{2\cos (50) \cos (50) \tan (30)}{\cos (80)}\right) = 70^\circ
$$
Thus the required $\angle{DAC} = 10^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

The regular 18-polygon has the nice property that each node sees all other nodes separated with $10^\circ$. Embed $\triangle{ABC}$ in this polygon as shown below.

[image: Solution]

Now use this polygon to construct the two equilateral triangles as illustrated, and consider the intersection of their drawn bisectors. 
This intersection is the center of a circle through A and C, and it is easy to verify that this center is $D$. Obviously $\triangle{ADC}$ is an isosceles, so $\angle{DAC} = \angle{DCA} = 10^\circ$