# Finding the angle $x$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

I tried a lot. Currently, I know the answer but I want to know how to solve it.

I need a mathematical or geometrical solution, not by measuring by any instrument.

Comment: Since you say you tried a lot, please include one or two tries you've made directly in your post.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799790/simplest-known-solution-to-worlds-hardest-easy-geometry-problem and references therein. This version is the "second hardest elementary geometry problem" so not quite a duplicate but close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have three different solutions and one general solution to your problem:
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: What software did you use to write this answer?

Comment: @Jack, I used the $Free$ C.a.r software to draw and typed in paint. You can download the software from here: http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with the triangle with $50$ and $60$ degrees to obtain $70$. Then use the straight line angle $180=z+70$ to obtain the adjacent angles. Then use $360=70+110+110+w$ to find the last angle of the crossing.